# How to make the Nether have the same Distance Ratio as the Over-world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am using the World-Border command to create a 600 x 600 world-border, but I don't know how to go about having the Nether be the same size as the Overworld, since I don't want a 75 x 75 block Nether (600 / 8 = 75).

Comment: I’m at least 90% sure world borders are the same on every dimension

Comment: I tested it, they are not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the same worldborder command in any dimension, just go to the nether and set it to 600 too!

Comment: You do not understand, people will be able to use the 1 = 8 blocks rule to get beyond the over-worlds border, how do i prevent that without making the nether 75 x 75 blocks?

Comment: Well, i found out that if you tried to build a portal outside the over-worlds border in the nether, then the portal puts you back inside the over-world's border.